# How to get UEFITool with New Engine?

Tags: github, uefi

UEFITool on Github has 3 branches (master, new engine & legacy).  Am I correct to assume the released version is only based on the master branch?  Would I have to compile the new engine version myself?  Anyone here willing to help do that?  I can't even figure out how to download the Qt5 library.

https://github.com/LongSoft/UEFITool

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Main author here: there are 2 branches that get release versions, from master you get UEFITool 0.xx.yy and UEFIPatch (because master is the only branch that can actually edit images), and from new_engine you get UEFITool NE Axx and UEFIExtract (new_engine branch have a lot of new parsers and overall much better internal design, but lacks editing support).

As for compiling new versions yourself: it's up to you, sometimes you want the absolute latest state of the both branches, so [build it yourself using the same commands CI does](https://github.com/LongSoft/UEFITool/blob/new_engine/.travis.yml), or [use releases tab](https://github.com/LongSoft/UEFITool/releases) to get latest release from.

I also think such questions should belong to the [project's issue tracker](https://github.com/LongSoft/UEFITool/issues).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Even after the explanation, it wasn't intuitive to me to expand the AXX release assets to find what you were saying. I'm also glad to know you'd rather see these kinds of questions in the issues tracker.  It seemed a little strange to ask such a non-technical question there but I'm on-board now.  Let me know if you prefer I re-post there.

Comment: Go ahead and repost, as the issue tracker is a better place for me and other contributors to actually track the issue. It could be framed as "needs better HOWTO:build documentation" or something like that. Once the issue is published and resolved, you can link it here and close this question as fully answered.